# Ridge regression derivation from Murphy Machine Learning

Tags: ridge-regression

Ridge regression, used to prevent overfitting, penalizes the coefficients $w_i$ of linear regression if they are too large. It is the solution to the problem

$$\arg\max_\textbf w \sum_{i=1}^N \ln \mathcal N(y_i|w_0+\textbf w^T\textbf x_i, \sigma^2)+\sum_{j=1}^D\ln\mathcal N(w_j|0,\tau^2)$$

(note the offset term $w_0$ is not regularized, since this just affects the height of hte function, not its complexity).

Expanding I get that we want to maximize wrt $\textbf w$

$$\begin{split}-\frac 1{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^N (y_i-w_0-\textbf w^T\textbf x_i)^2-\frac 1{2\tau^2}\sum _{j=1}^Dw_j^2&=-\frac 1{2\sigma^2}(y-w_0\textbf 1-\textbf X\textbf w)^T(y-w_0\textbf 1-\textbf X\textbf w)\\
&-\frac 1{2\tau^2}\textbf w^T\textbf w\end{split}$$

which is the same as minimizing

$$(y-w_0\textbf 1)^T\textbf X\textbf w+\textbf w^T\textbf X^T\textbf X\textbf w+\lambda\textbf w^TI_D\textbf w$$

where $\lambda=\sigma^2/\tau^2$. However, the Murphy book has a $\frac 1N$ as in minimizing $$J(\textbf w)=\frac 1N\sum_{i=1}^N (y_i-(w_0+\textbf w^T\textbf x_i))^2+\lambda \|\textbf w\|^2_2$$

which my derivation does not have. Taking the derivative (of my equation), and setting to $0$, we get

$$-2\textbf X^T(y-w_0\textbf 1)+2\textbf X^T\textbf X\textbf w+2\lambda I_D\textbf w=0$$

or

$$\textbf w=(\textbf X^T\textbf X+\lambda I_D)^{-1}\textbf X^T(y-w_0\textbf 1)$$

However, in the textbook the ridge regression coefficients are

$$\hat {\textbf w}_{ridge}=(\lambda \textbf I_D+\textbf X^T\textbf X)^{-1}\textbf X^T\textbf y$$

leaving out the intercept. I would like to be as precise as possible in these derivations. Is there any reason why there is a $\frac 1N$ term in $J(\textbf w)$ and why $w_0\textbf 1$ is left out in the final estimate - which is correct?

Comment: The $1/N$ term is more of a computational thing.  It prevents the loss from becoming overwhelmingly large due to having lots of data.  It also makes the loss between two models more or less comparable.

Answer (score 0):

It is because it is later stated in an exercise to assume that the $\textbf X$ is centered, i.e. the mean is subtracted from each variable. So we have $\textbf X^T(y-w_0\textbf 1)=\textbf X^Ty-\textbf 0=\textbf X^Ty$ for that part of expression of the ridge regression coefficient estimates.